# Rosaria P3-DX does not syn

Tags: rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to use a P3-DX pionner, I installed ROSARIA. When I try to use rosrun the robot does not syn.

[ INFO] [1439822848.983522504]: RosAria: using port: [/dev/ttyUSB0]
    Could not connect to simulator, connecting to robot through serial port /dev/ttyUSB0.
    Syncing 0
    No packet.
    Syncing 0
    No packet.
    Trying to close possible old connection
    Syncing 0
    No packet.
    Syncing 0
    No packet.
     Robot may be connected but not open, trying to dislodge.
    Syncing 0
    No packet.
     Robot may be connected but not open, trying to dislodge.
    Syncing 0
    No packet.
    Could not connect, no robot responding.
    Failed to connect to robot.
    [ERROR] [1439822855.737404764]: RosAria: ARIA could not connect to robot! (Check ~port parameter is correct, and permissions on port device.)
    [FATAL] [1439822855.737519583]: RosAria: ROS node setup failed... 



I've been checking several answers but so far no improvements. Any ideas on how to make this syn?

It's probably a port problem I don't understand  how this PORT thing works. I used the command sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0 and after this rosrun rosaria RosAria _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0.

Thx so much.


---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215989/rosaria-p3-dx-does-not-syn/) by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2015-08-17


Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the problem.

I had to EDIT the RosAria.cpp file.

In the file in the line 270 there is  n.param("baud", serial_baud, 0); This needs to be changed to your robot's baud rate. In my casen.param("baud", serial_baud, 115200);

Then catkin_make.

Now it connects! Progress!

---

Originally posted by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) with karma: 162 on 2015-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2015-08-19**:
The third argument in the `param` method is a default value for a node parameter.   In rosaria,  0 is used as a special case to let ARIA use its default value.   See my answer below regarding setting the value of the `baud` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can supply the connection baud rate to rosaria as a parameter (`~baud`).  See the rosaria documentation at http://wiki.ros.org/ROSARIA/   (you don't need to edit the source code)

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2015-08-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1